# Set image src in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5.3

**Controller Code**

```
myApp.controller("BaseController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.imgProcessingUrl = appUrl + "Images/ajax-loader.gif";
    }
]);
```

here appUrl  is `http://localhost/sample/public/`

**Html Code**

```
<img id="imgProcessing" ng-src="{{imgProcessingUrl}}" style="display:none;">
```

**master.blade.php**

```
<script>
    var appUrl = "{!! URL(''); !!}/";
</script>
```

Problem is: webpage always shows the rendered html like below.

```
<img id="imgProcessing" style="display:none;">
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: how and where are you defining appUrl?

Comment: Can you post the entire html?

Answer (score 1):

To make global variables available inside the controllers scope you must pass in the browsers `$window` object as a dependency.

```js
myApp.controller("BaseController", ["$scope", "$window", function($scope, $window) {
        $scope.imgProcessingUrl = $window.appUrl + "Images/ajax-loader.gif";
    }
]);
```

Comment: This is not 100% true in my case because I have no difficulty in getting value from appUrl without $window

Comment: @PankajGarg So can you `console.log(appUrl)` from with in the controller?

Comment: I already mentioned the value in my question. I have no problem in fetching the appUrl value :)

Comment: @PankajGarg So if you inject the $window service as I mentioned in my answer are saying that this solution doesn't work?